# laravel "<" converted to "&lt;"

Tags: php, html, laravel, html-table

I am trying to dynamically generate a table in laravel. However, when I generate the html is changes "<" (from `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>`) into `&lt;`

This means that it just prints out `<table>` etc in the browser, rather than crafting a table.

How do I stop this conversion from happening?

Comment: It is escaping the string.. Try with `{!! $var !!}`

Comment: Thanks  Sougata, this has worked. I was using {{ $var }} before

Comment: after laravel 5 update if i remember html escaping has changed. So just use {!! $var !!} or use plain old php echo ;)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Blade  `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
 {!! $str!!}
```